# Как лучше начать изучение C++?

Tags: c++, книги, c++11

Что необходимо прочитать, чтобы знать С++?

Изучаю по книге С. Прата "Язык программирования С++. Лекции и упражнения. 6 издание", описывается понятным языком, но всю картину портят маленькие "недочеты" вроде "Комментарий (прим. в коде) — это примечание, написанное программистом для пользователя программы..." я не знаю, как написано в оригинале, но прошу посоветовать переведенные книги, современного стандарта c++11(c++14), которые вы прочли и остались довольны.

Если Вам интересно, то я имею опыт несерьезного программирования на паскале, вроде решения вузовских задач. Также немного знаком с синтаксисом Java, в виде приложения для Android(но в голове от этого ничего не осталось). Изучать планирую серьезно, веду конспект. Изучаю прежде всего для разработки кросс-платформенных приложений, мобильной разработки вроде UE4, JNI, Android NDK. Я знаю, что книги гуглятся и возможно данный вопрос задавали 1000 раз, но прошу быть снисходительнее. Заранее спасибо за потраченное Вами время.

Comment: Я также постоянно имею опыт несерьезного программирования. :) Я бы посоветовал, но я сам не прочитал ни одной книги, содержащей описание C++ 11 и C++ 14. Тем не менее я бы рекомендовал к прочтению книгу Джосаттиса "Стандартная библиотека C++", которую уже сам полгода собираюсь прочесть.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Вы так написали, будто бы совсем не имеете опыта программирования, как я, однако судя по вашему профилю это далеко не так :) Вам виднее в любом случае, я прислушаюсь к любому совету и думаю Вам есть что посоветовать, пусть и без описания С++11, а книгу взял на заметку, спасибо!

Comment: Это все опыт несерьезного программирования.:) Весь мой опыт программирования на C++ ограничивается ответами на stackoverflow.com.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, быстро его активисты прихлопнули. Полчаса и готово.

Comment: @avp  Это вопрос-опросник. Его следует закрыть.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, Вы тоже согласны, что "опросники", "неоднозначники" и т.п. следует закрывать? (тогда зачем вообще на него отвечать?)

Comment: Я смотрел похожие вопросы, они звучат примерно также и не закрыты, я не хотел создавать вопроса, противоречащего правилам данного ресурса.

Comment: @avp  А моего ответа нет. Есть лишь мой комментарий к вопросу. В любом случае это - личное дело каждого.

Comment: @Side: у нас допустимы вопросы — списки литературы, но в достаточно жестком формате. Раньше не было, теперь сделали, смотрите: [Книги и другая литература по С++](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454263)

Comment: @Side, ссылка на вопрос с подборкой книг: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%A1